# How do I remove double quotes from values using awk gsub?

Tags: awk, gsub

I have a file that looks like this, it has seven columns:

```
"variant_id" "hg38_chr" "hg38_pos" "ref_allele" "alt_allele" "hg19_chr" "hg19_pos"
"chr10_100000235_C_T_b38" "chr10" "100000235" "C" "T" "chr10" 101759992
"chr10_100002628_A_C_b38" "chr10" "100002628" "A" "C" "chr10" 101762385
"chr10_100004827_A_C_b38" "chr10" "100004827" "A" "C" "chr10" 101764584
"chr10_100005358_G_C_b38" "chr10" "100005358" "G" "C" "chr10" 101765115
```

How can I get rid of the  double quotation marks so it looks like this:

```
variant_id hg38_chr hg38_pos ref_allele alt_allele hg19_chr hg19_pos
chr10_100000235_C_T_b38 chr10 100000235 C T chr10 101759992
chr10_100002628_A_C_b38 chr10 100002628 A C chr10 101762385
chr10_100004827_A_C_b38 chr10 100004827 A C chr10 101764584
chr10_100005358_G_C_b38 chr10 100005358 G C chr10 101765115
```

I know you can use the gsub function. How do I remove the double quotes from the column header name and every column value. What do I put in the ... section below to specify every field value?

```
awk 'gsub(/"/, "",  ...)' file
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is not working here? Sorry but its not clear.

Comment: `tr -d '"'` will do that.

Comment: …but if for some reason you _have to_ use `awk` and `gsub`: `awk '{ gsub(/"/, ""); print }'`

Comment: Please read the awk man page, it's very clear on how to use `gsub()`.

Comment: @Biffen  your answers are good, but on Windows your oneliners will get really ugly (Windows can't use single quotes. Double quotes have to be quoted, something like `"""` ). So in Windows, it's better to use a script file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do I put in the ... section below to specify every field value?

If you need to put something there then use `$0`, let `file.txt` content be

```
"variant_id" "hg38_chr" "hg38_pos" "ref_allele" "alt_allele" "hg19_chr" "hg19_pos"
"chr10_100000235_C_T_b38" "chr10" "100000235" "C" "T" "chr10" 101759992
"chr10_100002628_A_C_b38" "chr10" "100002628" "A" "C" "chr10" 101762385
"chr10_100004827_A_C_b38" "chr10" "100004827" "A" "C" "chr10" 101764584
"chr10_100005358_G_C_b38" "chr10" "100005358" "G" "C" "chr10" 101765115
```

then

```
awk 'gsub(/"/, "",  $0)' file.txt
```

gives output

```
variant_id hg38_chr hg38_pos ref_allele alt_allele hg19_chr hg19_pos
chr10_100000235_C_T_b38 chr10 100000235 C T chr10 101759992
chr10_100002628_A_C_b38 chr10 100002628 A C chr10 101762385
chr10_100004827_A_C_b38 chr10 100004827 A C chr10 101764584
chr10_100005358_G_C_b38 chr10 100005358 G C chr10 101765115
```

however 3rd argument to [`gsub` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-gsub_0028_0029-function-1) is optional

```
gsub(regexp, replacement [, target])
```

observe `[` and `]` denoting optional-ness, and not giving it is equivalent to giving `$0`, so earlier code is equivalent

```
awk 'gsub(/"/, "")' file.txt
```

be warned that code above does two things: jettison lines which do not have any `"` at all and print lines which have `"` with delete `"`s. If you wish to preserve lines without `"` then you might do

```
awk '{gsub(/"/, "")}{print}' file.txt
```

so `gsub` is action, not condition and `print` is indepent action applied to all lines.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: `{gsub(/"/, "")}{print}` would more commonly be written `{gsub(/"/, ""); print}`